# Why is there a break in the potion brewing times?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting, potions

I was looking over the rules for brewing potions in Pathfinder, and noticed something peculiar. The [Brew Potion feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/brew-potion-item-creation---final) says that if the base price is 250 gp or less, the potion only takes 2 hours to craft, but otherwise, it takes one day per 1000 gp.

Why is there such an arbitrary division? Why isn't the time listed as something like X hours per Y gp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where you are getting that from - [both the Core Rulebook and the SRD indicate that it takes one day to craft a potion, period](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Creating-Potions).

Comment: I believe it is the feat that lists the discrepancy.

Comment: Hmm, you're right, and the errata, FAQ, and even the forum posts I can find don't even notice/mention the discrepancy.  I always use the 1/day just because it's less fiddly.

Answer (score 9):

Magic items almost always take a minimum of a day to craft, but Pathfinder implemented a quick-crafting feature for certain low-level consumables that players are likely to craft a lot of (like first level potions and scrolls of, say, Cure Light Wounds).  The 2-hours-per-potion is an exception to the normal rules to allow you to craft cheap potions faster, letting you complete four potions in a day if they're all 250gp or less (so you complete the 1000gp or less per day that you'd normally get while crafting a higher-level item).

Comment: @GMJoe Yes, I mentioned it in my answer, just as an aside.

Comment: Whoops, missed that.

Answer (score 3):

The costs assume an eight hour workday, at about an hour per 125gp. But there's a two hour minimum (probably because of set up and clean up) and working on complex (i.e. expensive) potions will shoot your whole day with more complicated setup, ingredients, and procedures.